# Android Kotlin Firebase: How to assign default profile picture when user creates new account

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

How can I assign a default profile image when a user creates a new account?
Currently, after the user has created their account, they can go into my profile edit and change their profile picture as such:

```
val request: UserProfileChangeRequest =
            UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder().setPhotoUri(uri).build()
        currentUser?.updateProfile(request)?.addOnSuccessListener {
            //Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Profile Image Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }?.addOnFailureListener {
            //Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Failed to upload image please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
```

Would there be any way to assign a default profile picture before the user sets a custom one?

Comment: Here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_a_users_profile ,if the user signs in via google/facebook/twitter (as far as I'm aware only these 3 will get you a url)  you'll get the url to their profil  image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can in the `xml` add a default/initial image to the `imageview`. Then when the user changes it, just change the image using code?